# how to post json array on flutter

Tags: json, flutter, post

I have some problem to post json array with flutter.

When I hit api with postman using json it works. Screenshot postman:

[image]

Since I know on body just accept   Map <**String**,**String**> CMIIW

so i turn body into like this

```
List<Map<String,String>> products = [
  {
      "product_id": "1",
      "buy_quantity": "1",
      "product_price": "1000",
      "is_voucher": "0",
  },
  {
      "product_id": "2",
      "buy_quantity": "2",
      "product_price": "2000",
      "is_voucher": "0",
  },           
];

final String jsonProduct = json.encode(products);// here im trying to

Map<String,String> _body = {        
  "buyer_id": '',
  "buyer_firstname": postCart.buyerFirstname,
  "phone_number": postCart.phoneNumber,
  "transaction_total_price": postCart.transactionTotalPrice.toString(),
  "voucher_id": 0.toString(),
  "voucher_code": 0.toString(),
  "payment_id": postCart.paymentId.toString(),
  "payment_name": postCart.paymentName,  
  "products" : jsonProduct
};
```

but i still got error,

thanks!

Comment: sorry im newbie on ask question, sorry for the pict cant show, so i 'l write the json post on postman here

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are using the [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http).

This is an example of how to make an HTTP POST request with a json payload on the body:

```
Future<Lead> createLead(String clientName, String clientEmail, String clientPhone, String eventId) async {

  // Create storage
  final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

  // Get API url from env
  String url = (DotEnv().env['BASE_URL'] + "/leads/create");
  String authToken = await storage.read(key: 'api-token');

  // Create some request headers
  Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'X-Token': authToken
    };


  final response = await http.post(
    url,
    // enconde some JSON data on the request body
    body: json.encode(
      {
        'event_id': eventId,
        'name': clientName,
        'phone': clientPhone,
        'email': clientEmail
      }
    ),
    headers: requestHeaders
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final leadsJson = json.decode(response.body);
    Lead lead = Lead.fromJson(leadsJson);
    return lead;
  } else {
    // If that response was not OK, throw an error.
    // throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    return null;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve the JSON in the screen shot you need to make several changes.

1. Notice that the list of products shows unquoted integers when converted to JSON, so these need to be kept as `int`s in your Dart class. (Note the preferred syntax, too.)

```
var products = <Map<String, int>>[
  {
    'product_id': 1,
    'buy_quantity': 1,
    'product_price': 1000,
    'is_voucher': 0,
  },
  {
    'product_id': 2,
    'buy_quantity': 2,
    'product_price': 2000,
    'is_voucher': 0,
  },
];
```

2. The type of `_body` needs to change because it now contains a list as well as strings. (Keep the rest the same - like the `toString`s - as your screenshot shows that even the integers are quoted as strings.)

```
var _body = <String, dynamic>{
  'buyer_id': '',
  'buyer_firstname': postCart.buyerFirstname,
  'phone_number': postCart.phoneNumber,
  'transaction_total_price': postCart.transactionTotalPrice.toString(),
  'voucher_id': 0.toString(),
  'voucher_code': 0.toString(),
  'payment_id': postCart.paymentId.toString(),
  'payment_name': postCart.paymentName,
  'products': products
};
```

3. Lastly json and (preferably) utf8 encode the resulting map, and pass that as the `body` parameter of your `http.post`.

```
var bytes = utf8.encode(json.encode(_body));
await http.post(url, body: bytes, headers: someHeaders);
```

4. One of your headers could be `content-type: application/json;encoding=utf-8` to tell the server that you are sending UTF8 encoded JSON.